# roslaunch laser_mapper kitti_loop_closure.launch but the log show an error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been learning segmatch lately,and I refer to a website :

> https://github.com/ethz-asl/segmatch/wiki/Demonstrations

when I run:

> roslaunch laser_mapper kitti_loop_closure.launch

it can work but will show an error:

> auto-starting new master
> process[master]: started with pid [3377]
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
> setting /run_id to bfa6c998-76b9-11e7-ac3e-4d4164e69652
> process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3390]
> started core service [/rosout]
> process[visualizer-2]: started with pid [3414]
> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [laser_mapper/laser_mapper_node]: can't locate node [laser_mapper_node] in package [laser_mapper]
> process[player-4]: started with pid [3415]
> [ INFO] [1501592582.709331783]: Opening /home/wang/catkin_ws/src/segmatch/laser_mapper/demonstration_files/kitti/2011_09_30_drive_18.bag
> [ INFO] [1501592585.277767713]: rviz version 1.11.16
> [ INFO] [1501592585.277887573]: compiled against Qt version 4.8.6
> [ INFO] [1501592585.277936305]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
> [ INFO] [1501592586.765014947]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
> [ INFO] [1501592586.765184765]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
> Waiting 0.2 seconds after advertising topics... done.
> Hit space to toggle paused, or 's' to step.
> [RUNNING]  Bag Time: 1317376766.767944   Duration: 287.535898 / 287.641810
> Done.
> [player-4] process has finished cleanly
> log file: /home/wang/.ros/log/bfa6c998-76b9-11e7-ac3e-4d4164e69652/player-4*.log
> [visualizer-2] process has finished cleanly
> log file: /home/wang/.ros/log/bfa6c998-76b9-11e7-ac3e-4d4164e69652/visualizer-2*.log

When I open this directory but not find this file.This directory has：

> master.log  roslaunch-me-3365.log  rosout-1-stdout.log  rosout.log

In the master.log file,some of the errors are displayed

> [rosmaster.threadpool][ERROR] 2017-08-01 21:09:51,029: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/threadpool.py", line 218, in run
> result = cmd(*args)
> File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmaster/master_api.py", line 208, in publisher_update_task
> xmlrpcapi(api).publisherUpdate('/master', topic, pub_uris)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1233, in **call**
> return self.__send(self.__name, args)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1587, in __request
> verbose=self.__verbose
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1273, in request
> return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1306, in single_request
> return self.parse_response(response)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1482, in parse_response
> return u.close()
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 794, in close
> raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
> Fault: <Fault -1: 'publisherUpdate: unknown method name'>

what can I do?Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267828/roslaunch-laser_mapper-kitti_loop_closure.launch-but-the-log-show-an-error./) by [nature1949](https://answers.ros.org/users/31406/nature1949/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error `ERROR: cannot launch node of type [laser_mapper/laser_mapper_node]: can't locate node [laser_mapper_node] in package [laser_mapper]`seems to be regarding build/finding the node `laser_mapper_node`. Make sure the package `laser_mapper` is built and sourced, and check if you can run `rosrun laser_mapper laser_mapper_node`

---

Originally posted by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) with karma: 161 on 2017-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0